# Recursive deletion of base folder where all content is not modyfied older than n days

Tags: bash

I have some folders which needs my regular attention:
dir1
dir2
dir3

I know that I can safely remove them if anything inside has not been changed for 10 days. But how to do it?
I wanted to use "find /basedir/ -maxdepth 1 -mtime +10 -print | xargs -1 rm -f"

But this deletes those dirs which has not been modyfied but even if inside those folders were modyfied. Incomplete content of any of dir1,dir2 or dir3 is useless so I need to decide if delete whole dir1-3 or leave it based on how old complete content is.
Does anyone know easy way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `-maxdepth`. Iterate over the directories in a for loop:

```
for dir in /basedir/dir{1,2,3} ; do
    if ! find "$dir" -mtime -10 | grep -q ^ ; then
        rm -rf "$dir"
    fi
done
```